# Efficient local transport for ActiveMQ broker

Tags: activemq-classic

I have multiple applications (the producers) that produce messages to be processed by another application (the consumer). The messages will be sent through an ActiveMQ broker running on the same server. I don't have access to the applications' code, therefore the messages will be produced by executing a script (I currently don't know which language to use). The consumers will be Java application that will process the received messages.

I'm looking for an efficient transport that fits my use case. The VM transport cannot be used here. Also, I would like to avoid opening a TCP connection with the broker every time the producer script is executed (i.e. I would like to avoid using the TCP transport). I thought that UDP may be a good fit unless you know another transport which is more appropriate.

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 0):

There are pros and cons of both the `TCP and UDP` protocol

1)If ordering of messages and reliable-delivery of messages doesn't matter to you then UDP might be a nice choice,moreover in UDP it can also happen that duplicate messages are delievered to broker.

2)Using TCP offers reliable-delivery of messages along  with ordering, but if you want to eliminate the stream Transport delay of TCP then you might think against it.

There are couple of others as well which you can retrospect based on your requirements

- NIO protocol(USed in case of high traffic requirements)
- HTTP protocol(In case you want to bypass firewalls)

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: Ordering is not important in my case. Reliability is important but UDP should be good enough when used intra server. However, I didn't find a way to produce messages on UDP transport using a scripting language (e.g. Perl, Python, Shell...). There are libaries available to use with Perl and Python but they use the STOMP transport.

Comment: Really dont know about the libraries available but just a thought.. cant you use Java?

Comment: I think Java is too heavy for what I want to do. The producer applications code can't be modified but they can execute a command every time I need a message to be produced. Therefore, I thought to write a script to send the message. Of course, the command may consist of executing a Java app but this command will be called very often and I don't think booting a JVM every time a message has to be sent is a good idea.

Comment: ohh then finding some library seems the only way out